# why base64 images does not display in html

Tags: html, image, base64

I am attempting to embed base64-encoded images in my HTML code. However, when I include the base64 image code, it seems that there is an issue with my code, causing anything below the image to malfunction or not work as intended.

for example:

```html
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<body>
    <div>
<img src='data:image/png;base64,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
suRaplnutrxuhVo5WaVYVVpds0atna0l1rutu6cRp7lOk06rntZnw7Dxtsm2qbcZsOXYBtuutm22fWFnYhdnt8Wuw+6TvZN9un2N/T0HDYfZDq
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....'/> (long code)

</div>
</body>
</head></html>
```

I have tried to past different code but still I'm facing same issue, I need this code to past it on exception pages.

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense without a proper [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Is this your full base64 string? Just asking because it's ending with `...` which are not valid characters for such a string.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all self-closing HTML tags.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You put the closing `</head>` tag in the wrong place. Your base64 code is also incorrect. But the validator would have told you all that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to reduce your image size, check if the image code in base64 is correct, or split the base64 code using JavaScript

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img id="base64Image" src=''/>
    </div>

    <script>
        var base64Part1 = 'data:image/png;base64,iVB...';
        var base64Part2 = 'suRaplnutrxuhVo5WaVY...';
        
        // Concatenate base64 parts
        var base64Image = base64Part1 + base64Part2;
        
        // Set the concatenated base64 code as the image source
        document.getElementById('base64Image').src = base64Image;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which problem does your solution address? It's difficult to guess since your code also doesn't show an image and there's nothing below the image to "malfunction or not work as intended".

Comment: It's better not to answer vague questions like this.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Maybe the line breaks in the real code are the problem, since the one shown here is cropped and that is why it obviously does not show an image in the snippet. Maybe including all the information from JS could work for him, anyway, if Rahaf has asked a question/ error that is happening to him, I don't lose anything by answering

Comment: Yes, pointing out the line breaks is a valid point, however, you don't do that in your answer. Also, line breaks are normal in base64 and accepted by browsers, so that cannot be the problem here.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yes, I know that line breaks are allowed, but in my answer I break the code into several parts, associating it with variables so, just in case, line breaks in the html itself could cause an error, and then join them in a variable which I use as src. from the img tag

Comment: @KIKOSoftware but also before showing the code I recommend him that reduce the size of his image or regenerate the image code in case that was the error before touching the code

Comment: @HugoJiménez But those are guesses, and we don't guess answers on Stack Overflow.  OP might add additional information which might invalidate all the answers. We expect users to ask complete and clear questions. If we have to guess, the question should be closed until OP provides enough information to be able to answer it. In such a case, it is best not to answer. (As described under ["Answer well-asked questions"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem with your base 64 code. I tried with another image and it worked fine  I used this [site](https://base64.guru/converter/encode/image/png)   to generate base64 code and replaced with your's.

as mentioned by @AlexBerge Try removing the 3dots in the end of the img src string. you'll see the transparent image.

```html
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<body>
   
   
   <div>
<img   src="data:image/png;base64,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">  

</div>
your transparent image after removing 4 dots at the end of base64 code

<img width="50" style="border: 1px solid red" src='data:image/png;base64,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
suRaplnutrxuhVo5WaVYVVpds0atna0l1rutu6cRp7lOk06rntZnw7Dxtsm2qbcZsOXYBtuutm22fWFnYhdnt8Wuw+6TvZN9un2N/T0HDYfZDq
sdWh1+c7RyFDpWOt6azpzuP33F9JbpL2dYzxDP2DPjthPLKcRpnVOb00dnF2e5c4PziIuJS4LLLpc+Lpsbxt3IveRKdPVxXeF60vWdm7Obwu2o26/uNu5p7ofcn8w0nymeWTNz0MPIQ+BR5dE/C5+VMGvfrH5PQ0+BZ7XnIy9jL5FXrdewt6V3qvdh7xc+9j5yn+M+4zw33jLeWV/MN8C3yLfLT8Nvnl+F30N/I/9k/3r/0QCngCUBZwOJgUGBWwL7+Hp8Ib+OPzrbZfay2e1BjKC5QRVBj4KtguXBrSFoyOyQrSH355jOkc5pDoVQfujW0Adh5mGLw34MJ4WHhVeGP45wiFga0TGXNXfR3ENz30T6RJZE3ptnMU85ry1KNSo+qi5qPNo3ujS6P8YuZlnM1VidWElsSxw5LiquNm5svt/87fOH4p3iC+N7F5gvyF1weaHOwvSFpxapLhIsOpZATIhOOJTwQRAqqBaMJfITdyWOCnnCHcJnIi/RNtGI2ENcKh5O8kgqTXqS7JG8NXkkxTOlLOW5hCepkLxMDUzdmzqeFpp2IG0yPTq9MYOSkZBxQqohTZO2Z+pn5mZ2y6xlhbL+xW6Lty8elQfJa7OQrAVZLQq2QqboVFoo1yoHsmdlV2a/zYnKOZarnivN7cyzytuQN5zvn//tEsIS4ZK2pYZLVy0dWOa9rGo5sjxxedsK4xUFK4ZWBqw8uIq2Km3VT6vtV5eufr0mek1rgV7ByoLBtQFr6wtVCuWFfevc1+1dT1gvWd+1YfqGnRs+FYmKrhTbF5cVf9go3HjlG4dvyr+Z3JS0qavEuWTPZtJm6ebeLZ5bDpaql+aXDm4N2dq0Dd9WtO319kXbL5fNKNu7g7ZDuaO/PLi8ZafJzs07P1SkVPRU+lQ27tLdtWHX+G7R7ht7vPY07NXbW7z3/T7JvttVAVVN1WbVZftJ+7P3P66Jqun4lvttXa1ObXHtxwPSA/0HIw6217nU1R3SPVRSj9Yr60cOxx++/p3vdy0NNg1VjZzG4iNwRHnk6fcJ3/ceDTradox7rOEH0x92HWcdL2pCmvKaRptTmvtbYlu6T8w+0dbq3nr8R9sfD5w0PFl5SvNUyWna6YLTk2fyz4ydlZ19fi753GDborZ752PO32oPb++6EHTh0kX/i+c7vDvOXPK4dPKy2+UTV7hXmq86X23qdOo8/pPTT8e7nLuarrlca7nuer21e2b36RueN87d9L158Rb/1tWeOT3dvfN6b/fF9/XfFt1+cif9zsu72Xcn7q28T7xf9EDtQdlD3YfVP1v+3Njv3H9qwHeg89HcR/cGhYPP/pH1jw9DBY+Zj8uGDYbrnjg+OTniP3L96fynQ89kzyaeF/6i/suuFxYvfvjV69fO0ZjRoZfyl5O/bXyl/erA6xmv28bCxh6+yXgzMV70VvvtwXfcdx3vo98PT+R8IH8o/2j5sfVT0Kf7kxmTk/8EA5jz/GMzLdsAAAAgY0hSTQAAeiUAAICDAAD5/wAAgOkAAHUwAADqYAAAOpgAABdvkl/FRgACnkFJREFUeNrs/XmcLNl12HeecyMis/b17Uuv6AUNAmhsTRAgSGwkQIIUKZIgKWohRS20ZWkk62ON7ZFtWZatj2VLlu0Zj8eSRpI1siiLkihZICmB4AISBEEsBBqNRqP3fv32eu/VvuQScc/8UZX94mVlVmVl5RIZ8ft+urrqZUVG5o2MjHvvqZPnqpkJAAAAAAAAAGC0OQ4BAAAAAAAAAIw+gr0AAAAAAAAAkAMEewEAAAAAAAAgBwj2AgAAAAAAAEAOEOwFAAAAAAAAgBwg2AsAAAAAAAAAOUCwFwAAAAAAAABygGAvAAAAAAAAAOQAwV4AAAAAAAAAyAGCvQAAAAAAAACQAwR7AQAAAAAAACAHCPYCAAAAAAAAQA4Q7AUAAAAAAACAHCDYCwAAAAAAAAA5QLAXAAAAAAAAAHKAYC8AAAAAAAAA5ADBXgAAAAAAAADIAYK9AAAAAAAAAJADBHsBAAAAAAAAIAcI9gIAAAAAAABADhDsBQAAAAAAAIAcINgLAAAAAAAAADlAsBcAAAAAAAAAcoBgLwAAAAAAAADkAMFeAAAAAAAAAMgBgr0AAAAAAAAAkAMEewEAAAAAAAAgBwj2AgAAAAAAAEAOEOwFAAAAAAAAgBwg2AsAAAAAAAAAOUCwFwAAAAAAAABygGAvAAAAAAAAAOQAwV4AAAAAAAAAyAGC'/>



</body>
</head></html>
```

Comment: You didn't notice the invalid markup?

Comment: It is working, Thank you. The issue was image size.

Comment: It is working, Thank you. The issue was image size.